# How to troubleshoot a usb device not recognized warning

Tags: usb

How to troubleshoot a usb device not recognized warning? How do I solve this problem?
The flash drive that I'm trying to access works on our office computer. But not in my laptop. 
The flash drive is also super slow when I accessed it in the office computer. 
Please comment if you need more details.

Comment: It sounds like the device is starting to fail.  It sounds like you are stuck at USB 1.1 speeds which might explain the reason it doesn't work on your computer.  Honestly I would get a new drive or at least verify the port your using works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drive is most probably failing. I would just pull all the data off it and get a new one. Not a whole lot you can do.